# regex match all urls whitout an especial urladress: youtube.com

Tags: regex

I have following term to match Urls from a String:

`@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@`

Now i want match all URLs without `http://www.youtube.com` URLs.

Demonstration on [wordcreator.org](http://www.wordcreator.org/woerter.php?q=youtube)

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports negative lookahead, you can do this:

```
@(https?://(?!www\.youtube\.com)([-\w.]+)+?(/([\w/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern to try:

```
@(https?://(?!www\.youtube\.com)[^ ]+\.[^ ]+)@
```